# Huawei Share not working with macOS Catalina

Tags: macos-catalina

I recently upgraded my macOS from Mojave to Catalina Beta. Before upgrading the OS, I was able to access my Huawei Mate 20 Pro files through Huawei Share. I had sent a User ID and Password for Huawei share as well. But now after the upgrade I am not able to login to Huawei Share through my macOS using the same User ID and Password.

The way we connect to Huawei Mate 20 Pro using Huawei Share is as below:

1. Activate the "Huawei Share" option on the Huawei Phone
2. Active the "Computer Share" option on the same menu on the Phone
3. Go to Network on macOS and click on the Phone name
4. Enter User ID and Password as set for Huawei Share on the Phone

Can this be a problem with macOS Catalina Beta software?? I have searched google but could not find any solution to this.

Someone please help!!

Thanks,
Ujjwal

Comment: I've the same problem too, can't connect using huawei and your password.